# How can I auto-login with the latest Raspbian Stretch Lite?

Tags: linux, raspbian

I have read many questions regarding this, but none that I have seen had helped me. I want to sign on to an account on boot automatically, for example, username: user; password: password. How can I do this?

Comment: console or gui?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/), [Internet of Things Stack Exchange](http://iot.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Toxic alert !!!

Comment: This is not off-topic, I surely hope you don't use Stack Overflow just to go around telling random posts that, because that is ridiculous. It's not in the tiniest bit off-topic, it has to do with PROGRAMMING a system to work properly, or as intended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made this file: /etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/autologin.conf
And put this in it:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --autologin <user> --noclear %I 38400 linux
```

Give your username there without <> After that, I executed this:

```
sudo systemctl enable getty@tty1.service
```

Just reboot and see